# Interfaces and shared implementation

Tags: c#, interface

I have this interface

```
public interface IColumn
{
    bool IsVisible {get;set;}

    bool IsGroupBy { get; set; }

    Type CLRType { get; set; }

    string GetGroupByString();

    string GetFilterString();
}
```

and i have classes which will inherit from it, for the first 3 properties the implementation is exactly the same.

for `string GetGroupByString();` the implementation is the same for all classes except 2

so i made an abstract class called `ColumnBase` which inherits the `IColumn` interface and implements all of its members and added backing fields because i need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

and made my classes inherit from ColumnBase and i did override the implmentations that are not meant to be the same.

I have a very limited experience with Interfaces and Abstract classes, my question is if you had an Interface and some classes that will inherit from it and you realized that the implementation for some but not all properties and functions is the same, do you create an abstract class and put the default implementation and override it inside the classes that have special implementation?

Comment: yes, that seems like a good solution. Mark the methods you allow to override as `virtual` and specify the specific subclass behaviour in the subclasses.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel but what difference does virtual make?

Comment: it will prevent method-hiding issues depending on how abstract your variable is defined. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx) should make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you answers based on opinion and preference.

IMHO, I think this would be best suited to an abstract class with the two methods requiring differing implementations being declared as abstract methods; using abstract on the methods means that the implementations must have an implementation of that method.

```
   public abstract class ColumnBase
{
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    public bool IsGroupBy { get; set; }

    public Type CLRType { get; set; }

    public virtual string GetGroupByString()
    {
        return "base string";
    }

    public abstract string GetFilterString();
}

public class ConcreteColumn : ColumnBase
{
    public override string GetGroupByString()
    {
        return "concrete string";
    }

    public override string GetFilterString()
    {
        return "who owns the filter string?";
    }
}
```

Comment: but for string GetGroupByString(); the implementation is the same for all classes except 2, that means with the above i have to write the same implementation inside each class again and again?

Comment: He could make it virtual and then override it in others.

Answer (score 1):

> do you create an abstract class and put the default implementation and override it inside the classes that have special implementation?

Yes, I would do it exactly.Actually it's kind a purpose of `abstract` classes and `virtual / override` features.In your case I think you don't need `IColumn` interface,you can use an abstract class.And implement all common methods inside of it, then if you want to change behavior of a method override it in nested class.

If you mark a method with `virtual` you can override it in nested classes and you can change the behaviour of this method depends on your current class.You might want take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If your derived class is some specialized version of the base class then it would be a good idea to inherit it from the a base class, like `class Rectangle : Shape`. This why the derived classes are all specialized version of a same thing. For example Rectangle and Circle are in fact, inherently a shape. But consider using interfaces when you have **different** objects and you want some similar behaviors. For instance, you can serialize a `Bird` object and a `Chair` object, even if they have only `Name` and `Age` properties, it's not a good idea to derive them form a base class which has a `Name` and `Age` properties and `Serialize()` method, because they are different things. Although the implementation of `Serialize()` method would be the same in both of them, it's better to have an `ISerializable` interface and implement it in both classes.